# Disable kendo dropdown list Keyboard navigation

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I want to disable kendo drop down list Keyboard navigation which is the default behavior:

[DropDownList / Keyboard navigation](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/keyboard-navigation)

In my specific case I have a drop down inside editable grid and I want to disable changing the  highlights next/previous item when pressing the left/right arrows because I am using these to do another behavior (change focus to next column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer

It seems that the secret is in turning off the keydown event on dropdown first:

```
.off("keydown")
```

here is a working code in Code Pen where I disabled right and left arrows and enabled other keys:
http://codepen.io/MohQut/pen/vEKBvz

Comment: I am able to see that keyboard event is fired when the drop down is opened.

Comment: If you open it using the mouse then no it isn't fire

Comment: Hmmm. ok. But is there a way to prevent it when we open it using mouse ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to prevent keyboard navigation when the dropdown is opened using mouse and allow it when it is opened using keyboard? or what exactly, please explain in details what you want to do!

Comment: I mean to say disable keyboard navigation completely. For mouse as well as keyboard. 

The drop down should not get affected whatever i press on my keyboard regardless its open or not.

BTW, Well I have found a work around for my issue. its a tweak, by disabling the keydown event on its wrapper through jquery.

Comment: I am glad that you did